# Can flute of the outer gods be used against epic monsters?

Tags: eldritch-horror

This card allows one to "defeat all monsters." Epic monsters cannot be discarded but can they be defeated with this card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they can't.

> An Epic Monster cannot be defeated by any effect except losing
>   Health equal to or greater than its toughness.

Source: [Reference Guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/EH01%20Reference%20Guide.pdf), "Epic Monster" (page 6)

Comment: But this loss of health can be incurred by means such as Dynamite, Agency Quarantine or Shriveling which do damage to monsters, right?

Comment: @Joey Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Joey Right - it basically means you can't shortcut them using insta-kill mechanics, but you can still blow them up!